# Tooltips shows up behind taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Tooltips for taskbar icons in the hidden icons popup keep showing up behind the taskbar. For some of these, I can't see the tooltip at all. This makes it very difficult to differentiate between them.

[image: taskbartooltip]

Comment: look at mine. It looks like you have some kind of bizarre theme like thing. Have you installed something that changed how your windows look?  your borders are funny too and your tooltips look funny. contrast with mine.  http://i.imgur.com/5klkQzZ.png

Comment: @barlop: He's using Aero Glass.  This is completely normal.  I suspect he's also using high DPI

Comment: The only thing I'm doing strange is that I've got my taskbar located on the left side of the screen. It is locked with aero peek turned on (if that matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [5 Ways to Fix Windows Tooltips Showing Behind the Taskbar](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-windows-tooltips-showing-behind-taskbar/) :

> This is a well known bug that causes the taskbar tooltips to lose
>   their "topmost" window status and be covered up by the taskbar.
>   Microsoft acknowledged this tooltip problem existed back in 2006 but
>   didn’t get around to doing anything about it until 2008 when XP
>   Service Pack 3 came out. This cured most of the problems, but even
>   today there are still reports of XP SP3, Vista and even Windows 7
>   users experiencing this issue from time to time.

The article proposes the following solutions :

1. Use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and enter (every time this happens) :
   `C:\WINDOWS\nircmd.exe win settopmost class "tooltips_class32" 1`
2. Use NeoSmart [ToolTipFixer](http://neosmart.net/ToolTipFixer/) that can run as a Windows Service for permanent fix.
3. A compiled AutoHotkey Script written specially to fix this problem : [ToolTipFix.exe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4le2owypmmq0dw/ToolTipFix.exe).

Comment: The tooltip issue is not happening right now on my computer. I'm not sure what happened to fix it this time. I will verify one of these solutions once the problem occurs again.

Comment: I should add that solution 5 does not work on Windows 7 because the "Sort by Name" menu item is not available on the context menu.

Comment: Right - #5 deleted.

Comment: This bug happens less frequently on Win7 and it is many times fixed by a logout or reboot.

Comment: This just happened to me. The AutoHotKey script (#4) was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work; even when running as Administrator. I realized that #2 isn't relevant for Windows 7 either. The NirCmd utility website doesn't list Windows 7 as a supported OS, but I tried it anyway. It worked! Never got to try #3.